# Multiple PrimeFaces global p:confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, confirm-dialog

I looked at the example for confirmDialogs on Primefaces (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml)
[image]

And I was wondering if it is possible to reuse the confirmDialog structure twice.
More specifically, I have two different extremely common confirm dialogs that could use the structure, but I've been capable of using it only once (by adding the field "global = true" to the confirmDialog). Is it a way to bind the confirm to a specific confirmDialog through ID or something similar? So that I could then have two "global" confirmDialog and decide which of the two to use depending on the need.

Comment: Yes, but can it be used twice? As in a version A and a version B and for each UI command I decide whether it has to use the global confirm A or the global confirm B. And if not, if it is possible to get a behaviour of that kind in another way

Comment: No, I don't think so.